# Problem with tkinter label because of while loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a student who is new to Python . I had been trying to make a GUI stopwatch using python. When making the function for start button, as soon as I add while true to the program it stops working but if I remove the while True then it works fine except I have to make it manually work. Can anyone help me fix this? Here is code of the function:

`

```
def start(event):
    while True:
        abc = l5.cget("text")
        abz = int(abc)
        abd = abz + 1
        time.sleep(1)
        
        if abd < 10:
            wxy = str(abd)
            xfo = "0" + wxy
            l5.config(text = xfo)
            

        elif abd >= 10 and abd <60:
            wxy = str(abd)
            l5.config(text = wxy)
        elif abd == 60:
            l5.config(text = "00")
```

Here l5 is a label and start function has been binded to a start button. As soon as I remove while True it works fine but then I have to manually click on the button again and again to make stopwatch work. While want I want is that once I click on start button it should start running. But it is not sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

Now I have myself figured out solution. Due to the while loop, master.mainloop() does not get executed so what we can do is type master.update () after the last elif statement and it will work.